# Is there a bluetooth-alike protocol for WiFi?

Tags: android, streaming

For example, no matter what music app I am using, it can always play via bluetooth media devices.

So is there such a thing for WiFi? I can accept installing some thing on Android (sound source) side.

For the WiFi speaker, right now in my mind, is a speaker connected on RaspPi.

PS: I posted the question here, instead of Android forum, is because I think there is also something needed on RaspPi.

Comment: it is unclear what this means `For the WiFi speaker, right now in my mind, is a speaker connected on RaspPi.` ... please explain what you mean by that statement.

Comment: I meant physically. And for the concept, it is something similar with bluetooth speaker, except the wireless protocol runs on WiFi.

Comment: interesting idea .... there may already be something like that .... bluetooth technology is very much similar to wifi ...... there may be a problem with synchronizing speakers to deliver multi channel sound .... you could have the RPi play music from a webpage using a browser .... there may be a way to serve the left and right channels as two separate links on the webpage ..... the other way would be to stream the music and have the RPi play only one channel